# Why do some feeds not work in chat?

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, chat

I've been trying to add the [RPG Bloggers Network RSS feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/rpgbloggers?format=atom) to the chat, and just can't make it work.  It's a feedburner feed, and we have one of those working for [Gnome Stew](http://feeds.feedburner.com/GnomeStew). I've tried playing with the format - setting it to atom, etc. - and still no love.  What is wrong?  Is there a specific format it requires that I'm missing?

Comment: Is this working now? If it is, can you [meta-tag:status-completed] it? If it is no longer relevant, do you mind deleting?

Comment: I don't think it's working (we have several feeds configured and only Gnome Stew have I ever seen work). Still using the feedburner feed balpha made below, and it even has post dates now. http://feeds.feedburner.com/feedburner/VKtY

Comment: OK. Guess this gets marked with status-declined then...

Comment: Actually, I have one user saying he sees it... I can't see it in Firefox or IE... Is there a "make the feed items area appear"command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feed returns RSS 0.92; chat currently doesn't handle that. The `?format` parameter doesn't seem to have any impact – are you sure it should? I haven't found any documentation on that.

You can however use Feedburner to convert the format. I have created a custom feedburner feed using the RPG Bloggers feed as input and converting it to RSS 2.0: http://feeds.feedburner.com/feedburner/VKtY

The chat reads that just fine.

However, it looks like that feed (the original one) doesn't return post dates, which may cause problems.

Comment: format= changes the output type dynamically, compare http://feeds.feedburner.com/rpgbloggers?format=atom and http://feeds.feedburner.com/rpgbloggers?format=rss2.

Comment: @mxyzplk: Those two links have identical content.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right in that it's wonky though.  I hit format=rss and get a version with atom10 links, I hit with format=atom and I get something more HTMLey...

Comment: And I just added your feedburner link to The Game Table but I don't think it's working... It just shows the URL instead of resolving to a name and I'm not seeing anything come through yet.  Oh well.

Comment: @mxyzplk: Wait a couple of minutes -- The name is updated when the feed is first queried.

Comment: Ah, it has come through! Cool.  Thanks!

Comment: It works but ... a little wonky, the dates being Jan 1, 0001 and all...

Comment: doesn't seem to work any more.  one burst came through but nothing since.